# How do the React.lazy(), Suspense value received and add to state variable numbers

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-suspense

How can we use `React.lazy()` and `Suspense` in the below example. I am getting random value from `FirstComponent.js`. How do I use FirstComponent value to add to `newNumber` and display the total. So while rendering each time, we should get different total based on the random value received. Is that possible ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-lamarr-ny680?file=/src/App.js:0-635

```
import React, { Suspense, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const FirstComponent = React.lazy(() => import("./other/FirstComponent"));
const SecondComponent = React.lazy(() => import("./other/SecondComponent"));

export default function App() {
  const [newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
   const num1 = 100;
   setNewNumber(num1);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <section>
          <FirstComponent />
          {newNumber + FirstComponent}
        </section>
        <section>
          <SecondComponent />
        </section>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`FirstComponent.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const FirstComponent = () => {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const randomNumber = [];
    const data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
    randomNumber.push(data[random]);
    setNumbers(randomNumber);
  }, []);

  return <div>Hello First: {numbers}</div>;
};
export default FirstComponent;
```

`SecondComponent.js`

```
import React from "react";
const SecondComponent = () => {
  return <div>Hello Second</div>;
};
export default SecondComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a callback, as [data in React flows down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down).

```
const FirstComponent = React.lazy(() => import("./other/FirstComponent"));

export default function App() {
  const [newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState(0);
  const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setNewNumber(100);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <FirstComponent set={setRandomNumber} />
        {newNumber + randomNumber}
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

const FirstComponent = ({ set }) => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const randomNumber = data[random];
    setNumber(randomNumber);
    set(randomNumber);
  }, [set]);

  return <div>Random Number: {number}</div>;
};
```

[image: Edit gracious-dust-1s62g]